# Electric question

Tags: electrical, lighting, remodeling

new bathroom Remodel will require a 120V / 20A GFCI circuit and outlet by the lavatory sink, this can be shared with the now enlarged adjacent master bedroom's lighting/power circuit. Is it true?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Where are you located? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: That depends on your local electric codes. Please tell us, at a minimum, what country you're in. Region/state and even city would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not if in the US or other territory subject to the NEC. Section 210.11(C)(3) says the a 20A circuit feeding bathroom countertop work surface receptacles "shall have no other outlets" unless it feeds only one bathroom, then it can feed other outlets in the same bathroom only.

Comment: NEC definition of "outlet" is point of connection of utilization equipment, includes receptacles, fans, lights.

Answer (score 1):

What NoSparks says.  Basically, in a bathroom remodel, you must follow one of 2 rules:

- The circuit that serves the bathroom receptacles in this bathroom can ONLY serve other loads in this bathroom (light, fan etc.) *Note this rule can result in the lights going out when someone trips the circuit breaker.*

OR

- The circuit that serves bathroom receptacles can ONLY serve receptacles in this and other bathrooms (no light or fan; no other rooms).  *Note this rule does NOT get the *Vanity Fair* seal of approval as it will result in breaker trip anytime 2 people in different bathrooms try to use a hair dryer, curler, any bathroom heat appliance at the same time.*

Adds up to a dedicated circuit needed for the bathroom receps.